# Is Shared server effect SEO

Tags: seo, server, vps

Is Dedicate, VPS or shared server effect in SEO? What do you think how many website I can host in a single IP or I need to use different IP for different website?

Answer (score 1):

> Is Dedicate, VPS or shared server effect in SEO?

No, it doesn't matter.

> What do you think how many website I can host in a single IP or I need to use different IP for different website?

As much as you want, quantity doesn't matter. Many hosting providers keep thousands of sites on one server.